# How to understand what message from the telegram bot answered the user?

Tags: laravel, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I use Laravel Framework and Telegram Bot SDK. I looked at a lot of guides, and all say how easy it is to create a command and get an answer, but I can’t understand how to create dialogs between the user and the bot. In my webhook I can do for example:

```
$message = Telegram::getWebhookUpdates()->getMessage();
if ($message->getText() == 'something') 
   foreach (Service::get() as $item => $value){
      if($value->name == $message->getText()) {
         $credential = Credential::find($value->id);
         if($credential) {
            Telegram::sendMessage([
               'chat_id' => $message->getChat()->getId(),
               'text' => 'Enter the data'
            ]);
         }
      }
   }
}
Telegram::commandsHandler(true);
```

And after the user sends the data (in numerical format) I need to process the response. But how can I check the message text with a conditional statement, to know that this is the answer to my previous message, if it is any number. For example:

```
$message = Telegram::getWebhookUpdates()->getMessage();
if($message->getText() == '/start'){
   ...
}
elseif($message->getText() == **HERE USER RESPONSE WITH DATA**){
   ...
}
```

This is only part of the functionality, there are still different commands, variations of keyboards, and therefore I need to understand how to correctly process incoming messages in order to know which particular question I received the answer.

P.S. I found solutions that say that you need to create a database table with message history and based on this do handlers. Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by [ForceReply](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#forcereply) in Telegram Bots API. If user's message is a reply, you should find out which message a user replied to. Just check message's text using it's [message id](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message). If it's the first question, it means it has been answered and now you can send the second question.

PS: The solutions that you found is probably the better way to do the job. Just create a database table with message history.